# FileExistsAtPath returning NO on movie from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I saved a movie file's path from UIImagePickerController, and I know it exists because I can play it on the device. An NSLog on the string containing the movie file path returns this:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/E694555D-3959-4CC5-A829-4260323C2C65/tmp//trim.6JemAI.MOV
```

When this string is used like this however, it returns `NO`:

```
NSLog(@"file exists: %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:media.movie]);
```

Any idea this this is failing? Could it be related to the value being stored as a path, or perhaps that the path includes `//` at one point? These are just some thoughts I've had.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the URL to a file path.

```
NSURL *url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSString *path = [url path];
NSLog(@"file exists: %i", [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]);
```

A path doesn't have the leading `file://localhost`.